# How to Access cookies set with res.cookie from server side to the client browser, and now want to access them to server side

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to get it with document.cookie.split(';');, then i am getting an error as 
let user = document.cookie.split(';');
           ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object. (/home/codemymobile/study/trello/public/card-controller.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object. (/home/codemymobile/study/trello/index.js:8:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install cookie-parser and then

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser()); //add this on server setup
```

Now you can access the cookies using

```
req.cookies["cookieName"]
```

Answer (score 0):

document refers to the dom object in the browser. you cannot use it while running it on node.

Comment: @A R, so what should be the approch to get th values